# Allow users to choose multiple authentication methods with Azure Mobile Service

Tags: authentication, mobile, service, azure

I would like to allow my users to choose from all the available authentication options that Azure Mobile Services provides when signing in but I'm not sure how to link their accounts together if say they choose to authenticate with Facebook the first time and then the next time they run the application they choose a different service.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use a username that upon inserting to your table, you go through as to see if a username of this exists and then link it. Of course this could be a problem if another person wants to login with the same username.

The smartest thing is to retrive some information from the users account so you have some values you can see that are the same. And then you can link them inside.

You could look at this 
Windows Azure Multi-Factor Authentication: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/services/multi-factor-authentication/

Comment: If you are using a windows phone you can access phone Token such that you know the login comes from the same phone. Scrool down to  PrimaryToken http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769509(v=vs.105).aspx